# Python Return Most Common Element

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that returns the most common element from an array it is passed. My code looks like this:

```
def get_classification(classes):
    from collections import Counter
    count = Counter(classes)
    return count.most_common()[0]
```

And it is properly returning the most common element. However, it returns it in the format `element, count` such as:

`3.0, 2` 
`2.0, 3` 
`1.0, 3`

I don't want it to return that tuple. I *just* need it to return the most common element. How is that possible?

I have tried the solution:

```
counts = numpy.bincount(classes)
final = numpy.argmax(counts)

return final
```

But that did not work for me either.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second solution is easier, scroll down and see it

Comment: I was not able to get that solution to work for me, even after spending a half hour. @U9-Forward

Comment: Use: `max(set(classes), key=classes.count)`

Comment: Understood, I will retry, thank you. I'm sorry for duplicating, I did see that post and try it but to no avail @U9-Forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing again, to get the first element of the tuple:

```
def get_classification(classes):
    from collections import Counter
    count = Counter(classes)
    return count.most_common()[0][0]

print(get_classification([1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1])) # ==> 1
```